# Using a *ngFor inside a custom ng-template #treeNodeTemplate causes the tree to refresh infinitely, making the browser crash

Tags: angular, angular-tree-component

- Adding *ngFor to ng-template #treeNodeTemplate causes the tree to refresh infinitely.

Related to angular-tree-component with Angular 7.

```html
<tree-root [nodes]="data" #tree [options]="customTemplateStringOptions">
  <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
    <div class='model-tree-item'>
      <div>{{ node.data.getItemText() }}</div> <!-- supposed to get text from object -->

      <!-- This loop runs infinitely, getTestData() returns [1, 2, 3], keeps getting called -->
      <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="getTestData()" let-item>
        {{item}}
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</tree-root>
```

Tried this with simple

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3]"> (or getTestData(), same result)
```

This is the tree options object:

```js
  public customTemplateStringOptions: ITreeOptions = {
    // displayField: 'subTitle',
    // isExpandedField: 'expanded',
    idField: 'uuid',
    getChildren: this.getChildren.bind(this),
    nodeHeight: 23,
    allowDrag: (node) => {
      return false;
    },
    allowDrop: (node) => {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Here is getTestData():

```
getTestData() {
    console.log('test data');
    return [1, 2, 3];
  }
```

Results:
Console output after tree is rendered

```
test data
test data
test data
test data
test data
test data
...
```

This problem was opened in the following link but looks like it was never addressed as the poster did not respond:
[Problem Link](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/issues/444)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using a function as the `input` for a property binding e.g. `[ngForOf]="getTestData()"`

Angular tries to check if the input value has changed during the change detection cycle, and it expects the input value to be a variable in the template, or a property on the class. If it has to call a function to retrieve the value, it will simply call it indefinitely

Try setting the data as a property on the class - see if that narrows down the issue

Note: this is also why `pure pipes` are necessary

Answer (score 1):

Don't call methods from the template unless it is response to user action. You end up in a change detection loop.

Add a `number[]` property to the component:

```
testData: number[];
```

Have the component implement `OnInit` and set the value in `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.testData = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Change template to

```
<ng-template [ngForOf]="testData" let-item>
```

Comment: I even tried without the testData
```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3]">
```
this also gives same results

Comment: Did you also remove `{{ node.data.getItemText() }}`?

Comment: Yea, an update, its happening even without the for loop, could be the getItemText()